# Boostrap's Popover & Codeigniter loop doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get the "details" to be shown in a popover. However only the first element in the loop is showing then I tried using the modal instead and only 1 value showed everywhere when there are 5 rows.

```
{orders}
<tr>
    <td>{customer_name}</td>
    <td>{mobile_num}</td>
    <td>{lounge}</td>   
    <td>{date_reservation}<br/>{time_reservation}</td>
    <td>{date_posted}</td>
   <td><button id="example" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" 
            data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" 
            data-content="{details}">
            View
            </button></td>  
    <td><button class="confirm btn btn-primary" type="button">Confirm?</button></td>
</tr>   
{/orders}

<script>
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $(".confirm").confirm();
}
</script>
```

Comment: is that a typo. or your `.ready();` missed the closing.

Comment: the problem is that it doesn't display the rest of the popovers

Comment: Show us the generated HTML. And check what @kevinabelita says. You are missing the `);` in your `.ready` function.